# Node.js - using socks5 module

Tags: macos, node.js, socks

I'm on a Mac running OSX 10.8.2. I'm learning Node.js and want to do requests using socks.

In the Terminal I used

`git clone https://github.com/mattcg/socks5-http-client.git`

to get the socks5 http client source.

In the downloaded source folder is an example called example-tor, so I ran

`node example-tor.js`

This gives me a message saying "Cannot find module 'socks5-client'".

This error is being thrown in a js file in the source folder called **agent.js** on a line that says **var socksClient = require('socks5-client');**

**What am I doing wrong?**

To be honest, I am just beginning Node.js. I'm not sure if I fully understand how modules work, where they are located on my Mac and how Node.js is supposed to know where they are.

I have been running through the documentation, "hello world" tutorials and tutorials to install things like "npm" package manager but the whole process of getting something working seems very messy and unclear.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Did you try npm install socks5-client from your terminal in the folder of your node.js folder?

Comment: No I didn't. That is something I'm obviously unclear on. I thought that is what I downloaded from github. I will try your suggestion in the morning. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `npm install` from the terminal in the `socks5-http-client` top folder (the same one with the `package.json` file)

Comment: Wonderful. That is all it was. It's all a little bit clearer. Thanks.